# qt5 linux application use large memory size

Tags: linux, memory, qt5

All my Qt applications are using nearly 100MByte memory. For a test, I create an empty “qt widget application” with Qt-Creator. If I check the memory with pmap, the writeable/private memory is: 80472K. I don’t know what’s wrong. I'm using suse Linux laep 15 and Qt5.11.